# Using same AsyncTask subclass to make API call to different URLs

Tags: android, json, android-asynctask

I am storing the data that I parsed from the JSON that is returned by my API request into the Firebase database.

```
    submitButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String APIURL = "https://api.github.com/users/" + idInput.getText().toString();
            String repoURL = "https://api.github.com/users/" + idInput.getText().toString() + "/repos";
            new JSONTask().execute(APIURL);
            //new JSONTask().execute(repoURL);
            String parsedUserID = idInput.getText().toString();
            SM.sendDataToProfile(parsedUserID);
            viewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
            //addUser(parsedUserID);
        }
    });
```

When the button is clicked, it calls a new JSONTask (asynctask) on the APIURL.

**JSONTask**

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {
        @Override

        // Any non-UI thread process is running in this method. After completion, it sends the result to OnPostExecute
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            HttpURLConnection connection = null;
            BufferedReader reader = null;

            try {
                // Pass in a String and convert to URL
                URL url = new URL(params[0]);
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.connect();

                InputStream stream = connection.getInputStream();

                // Reads the data line by line
                reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream));
                StringBuffer strBuffer = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                    strBuffer.append(line);
                }

                // If we are able to get the data do below :
                String retreivedJson = strBuffer.toString();

                return retreivedJson;

                // When we are not able to retreive the Data
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {

                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally {
                if (connection != null) {
                    // close both connection and the reader
                    connection.disconnect();
                }
                try {
                    if (reader != null) {
                        reader.close();
                    }

                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

            return null;
        }
```

And it does parsing in another function.

My question is, as you can see on my setOnClickListener, I tried to make two JSONTask on two different URLs because the first URL gives me the information of the user and the second URL (repoURL) gives me the information of the user's repositories. I tried to fetch the repo info of the user and store it into the DB, but it seems like this is a wrong approach.

What is a right way to call two separate AsyncTasks on two different URLs?

**EDIT**

```
private void addUserRepo(final String githubID, final String[] repoList) {

    DatabaseReference users = databaseReference.child("users");

    users.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            List list = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(repoList));

            databaseReference.child("users").child(githubID).child("Repos").setValue(list);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


}
```

Using data parsed from

```
    public void formatJSONArray(String results){
        try {

             JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(results);

             RepoInfo[] repoList = new RepoInfo[jsonArray.length()];


             for(int i = 0; i < jsonArray.length(); i++){
                 JSONObject jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                 if(jsonObject.optString("name") != null) {
                     repoList[i].setRepoName(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                     //repoNameList.add(jsonObject.getString("name"));
                 }
                 if(jsonObject.optString("description") != null) {
                     repoList[i].setDescription(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                     //descriptionList.add(jsonObject.getString("description"));
                 }
                 if(jsonObject.optJSONObject("owner") != null){
                     JSONObject ownerObject=jsonObject.getJSONObject("owner");

                     if(ownerObject.optString("login")!=null) {
                         repoList[i].setOwner(ownerObject.getString("login"));
                         //userNameList.add(ownerObject.getString("login"));
                     }
                 }
             }


        } catch (JSONException jsonException){
        }
    }
```

Comment: Can you better describe what these two async calls are supposed to be doing?  Are they somehow dependent on one another or are they independent?

Comment: Sorry. In the "https://api.github.com/users/userId" API, it has basic profile info of the user and it also has an API URL to the user's repository "https://api.github.com/users/userId/repos". I am trying to first store the basic profile info into firebase DB (and I've done is successfully), but I am having trouble calling another API call from the repos URL and then store the repos information into a list and then add it to the DB. Plz check my edit for adding the repoList into DB.

Comment: I'll leave this as a comment, rather than an answer, but you can accomplish this if you stop using AsyncTask, and switch to using RxJava. RxJava allows executing code asynchronously, but you can use operators like `flatMap` to chain calls together that rely on each other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response of two different URLs will surely not be similar. So you need different parse methods for them.

One lazy way would be to use two different `AsyncTasks` subclasses for two different urls.

Another way would be to store a flag inside the asynctask indicating whether it is dealing with user or repo.

```
public class JSONTask extends AsyncTask <String , String , String> {
    boolean fetchingRepo;
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground (String... params) {
        fetchingRepo = params[0].endsWith("/repos");
        //other statements
    }
```

Now inside onPostExecute:

```
if(fetchingRepo){
    //parse one way
} else {
    //parse another way
}
```

Comment: If I use the flag method, will it work if I call the JSONTask twice? e.g. new JSONTask().execute(APIURL); new JSONTask().execute(repoURL);

Comment: Yes it will. Why would I post it if I don't think it will work? Why don't you try it?